# Is there any way to migrate Cassandra 1.2 data to Cassandra 1.1?

Tags: cassandra

I need to migrate some data in Cassandra 1.2.1 because we encountered a pretty bad bug. I want to move it to a 1.1.9 cluster that we know is pretty stable, but I can't get any of the export methods to work. I finally tried sstable2json and json2sstable, but now it looks like the json coming out of 1.2.x is different than the one coming out of 1.1.x

Answer (score 3):

The link Lyuben gives is useful, but for large data sets you'd want to use the [sstable loader](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading) rather than COPY TO / COPY FROM.  The latter is not parallelized and limited to the local disk space available.

Comment: I see. Is that supposed to work even if the 1.2 cluster was configured with the Murmur3Partitioner? I honestly would have not wanted to do this,but a nasty bug in production made me go back to 1.1.9. I posted about this here http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/datastax-12-community-on-day-1-of-launch-and-got-corrupt-sstables-and-went-down-for-hourslost-data?replies=1#post-9086 I couldn't repair any of the data so we lost quite a bit of it after restoring a snapshot. I ended up doing COPY TO. when i did a COPY FROM on the 1.1 side,the format was different so had 2 write custom importer

Comment: I would have really liked to go 1.2 to use virtual nodes, but I couldn't find any solutions to what happened. I asked several people more familiar than me with Cassandra and no one had a clue and we could not repair the damage.

Answer (score 1):

You could export the required data as a `SSTable` (Data structure used by Cassandra to store it's data) and then re-import it into Cassandra 1.1. You can read about the process from the [Datastax documentation](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/simple-data-importing-and-exporting-with-cassandra). The documentation includes examples at the bottom of the page.